# Running nmcli device shows all unmanaged

Tags: wireless, 22.04, network-manager, raspberrypi, ros

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXiVf.png)

Newbie, recently installed Ubuntu Server OS on Raspberry Pi 4. It shows networks are unmanaged, might also be the reason why ROS on dev machine can't communicate with ROS on Raspberry Pi when I tried the talker and listener demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu server uses Netplan to manage networks. Also note that you ran `nmcli device` which shows you the network interfaces rather than the connections (`nmcli connection`).

Your Netplan config should be in `/etc/netplan`

If you check the content of this file, `cat /etc/netplan`, this will show you your network config. you need to add or change the line below network

```
   network:
      renderer: NetworkManager
```

then run `netplan apply`

Just beware that you might lose connection until NetworkManager is set up, especially if you are running your Pi headless (no monitor and connected via ssh).

After editing the netplan config, make sure to enable the networkmanager service:

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Check that you have a connection `ip a` should output an ip address

If this does not output an ip address, try:

```
nmcli c up <connection_name>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: it worked thank you so much!